# Compile Python Error

Tags: python, compilation

I have a Code from Python 2.4 and Want to Compile this code on Python 2.6 but I see this Error:

```
>>> py_compile.compile("Model.py")

SyntaxError: ('invalid syntax', ('pcbModel.py', 73, 19, ' msg = "%s: %s. The error occurred generating \'%s\'." % (sys.exc_type, sys.exc_value, bName)\n'))
```

and code is:

```
        try:
            pcb.Create(self.skipMeshing, analysisType = self.analysisType)
        msg = "%s: %s. The error occurred generating '%s'." % (sys.exc_type, sys.exc_value, bName)
        raise Exception, msg

        continue
    self.deactivate(bName)
```

how solve it?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have a `try` clause, with no corresponding `except`.  also, `raise type, args` form is deprecated, use `raise type(args)`.  also, `sys.exc_type` and friends are not thread safe.  The syntactically correct version is:

```
# DON'T DO THIS, SEE BELOW
try:
    pcb.Create(self.skipMeshing, analysisType = self.analysisType)
except Exception as e:
    msg = "%s: %s. The error occurred generating '%s'." % (type(e), e, bName)
    raise Exception(msg)
```

However, It appears as though you are trying to "catch" the exception, compute some sort of error message and raise an exception.  exceptions already do that.  the idomatic version of the above is actually,

```
pcb.Create(self.skipMeshing, analysisType = self.analysisType)
```

with no `try`, no `except` and no `raise`.  If `pcb.Create()` raises an exception, it has already *raised* an exception, you don't need to raise another one.